# Multiplying the next number

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to write a program that multiplies an input number by 2, and then multiples that answer by 2 in a loop, however I can't get my program to multiply the second number, here's my code.

```
int main() {

    int number;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;

    while (true) {
        int multiply = number * 2;
        cout << "Answer: " << multiply << endl;
    }  
}
```

How do I make this program multiply the number that was previously multiplied? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are  storing in "multiply" the same value, again and again.

In order to reach your goal, you need to store your result in "multiply", then *2 this variable.
Something like this:

```
int multiply = number * 2;

while (true) {
    cout << "Answer: " << multiply << endl;
    multiply = multiply * 2;

}
```

EDIT:
a more elegant way to do this, is using recursive functions.
You can find a useful example [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson16.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Marco, I also found the recursive functions very helpful!

Answer (score 6):

Just re-use the same variable:

```
while (true) {
    number = number * 2; // The same !
    cout << "Answer: " << number << endl;
}
```

But don't expect the program to run correctly until the end of times: `int` variables have a maxmimum of (2^31 - 1), so it will be ok at max for 30 iterations.

Comment: Maybe comment that you can also multiply by 2 by shifting the bits: `number = number << 1`

Comment: @BenjyKessler You can, but I do not feel like that would make things clearer or better in any other way, so I don't think it has a place in this answer.

Comment: I don't think so. This user is probably a beginner at C/C++ code. To explain bit shift would not make things clearer. Especially with C++ `<<` operators just under it, that don't have any link but the same appearance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this also helped me, could you offer a link to bit shift?

Comment: Here is one : [bit shifts](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html), It's a way to make mutiplication or division by 2 or powers of 2, with a better execution speed than simple multiplication or division.

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
   int multiply = number;

    while (true) {

        multiply = multiply *2;
        cout << "Answer: " << multi << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`number` has the same value for each iteration. You want to multiply `multiply`   by two each time, not `number`.

The first iteration is the special case so you'll have to figure out how to initialize `multiply` so that it works.